# Optimization of three variables with a constraint

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I have a question puzzling me for a while. I tried using Lagrange multipliers, however it began to get messy as well as the fact that i am new to the method of Lagrange multipliers!

The question is to find the minimum values for the variables $a, b, c$ of the following expression
$$\frac{a}{b^3+54}+\frac{b}{c^3+54}+\frac{c}{a^3+54}$$

What would be the easiest process and what would be the answer. Thank you!

**EDIT: I have been notified that I had forgot the constraint by simple accident, my bad, Ha-ha. The constraint is $a+b+c=\frac{9}{2}$

Comment: What's the constraint?

Comment: If there is no constraint the problem is unbounded, as suggested by Kaster.

Comment: Ahhh off course i forgot, my bad. The constraint is a+b+c=4.5